# If all elements in bool array are true?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having difficulty using the `array.All<>` function.

```
private bool noBricksLeft() {
    bool[] dead = new bool[brick.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < brick.GetLength(0); i++) {
        if (brickLocation[i, 2] == 0)
            dead[i] = true;
        else
            continue; // move onto the next brick
    }

    if (dead.All(dead[] == true)) // IF ALL OF THE ELEMENTS ARE TRUE
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I'm wondering how I can achieve `if (dead.All(dead[] == true))`?

Comment: You can use `return dead.All(x => x);`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can simply use a *lambda-expression*:

```
if (dead.All(x => x))
```

Given you `using System.Linq`'s [`IEnumerable<T>.All` <sup>[msdn]</sup>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

will do the trick. Furthermore an `if` statement that returns the answer is useless, so you can rewrite it to:

```
private bool noBricksLeft() {
    bool[] dead = new bool[brick.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < brick.GetLength(0); i++) {
        if (brickLocation[i, 2] == 0)
            dead[i] = true;
        else
            continue; //move onto the next brick
    }

    return dead.All(x => x);
}
```

Another idea, partly borrowed from [@royhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34214414/67579) is the following:

```
private bool noBricksLeft() {
    return Enumerable.Range(0,brick.Length).All(i => brickLocation[i,2] == 0);
}
```

Comment: The lack of a predicate-free `All` is not that weird. `Any(pred)` is true if there's at least one matching element and `Any()` is true if there's at least one element, false otherwise so it's essentially `Any(x => true)`, . `All(pred)` is false if there's at least one non-matching element and so a `All()` that was likewise equivalent to `All(x => true)` would just always return true.

Comment: You are right in the sense that `Any()` without any arguments means there is at least one element. It is however a bit "problematic" because for a list of boolean an intuitive interpretation could be, whether one element is `true` (not whether the list contains one element). In other words one could have defined an `Any` for IEnumerable<Bool>`. And use a *different name* for whether there is at least one element.

Comment: I don't know c#, but is there no way to incorporate the `brickLocation[i, 2] == 0` check into `.All` so you only have to iterate the array once?

Comment: @royhowie: yes, in this case you can use `Enumerable.Range` as a generator for indices. Your answer by the was is a nice improvement of the OP's algorithm. +1

Comment: @JonHanna Except, an overload of `All` without a predicate (specifically for boolean values) would be equivalent to `All(x => x)` and not `All(x => true)`, which is broken, as it always returns true, and doesn't take the actual boolean value into account. I think the decision to omit a parameterless version of `All` comes down to the fact that it would only apply to boolean values, and would therefore not be generic.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use `.All`, but your code still isn't very nice. From what I understand, you can rewrite your code like this, without using an array:

```
private bool noBricksLeft () {
    for (int i = 0; i < brick.GetLength(0); i++) {
        // inverted your condition; we can short-circuit
        // and just return false
        if (brickLocation[i, 2] != 0)
            return false;
    }
    // every brick passed our condition, so return true
    return true;
}
```

Comment: While my and CommuSoft's answers focus on the correct syntax of using all, your answer is also useful for guiding the OP to the correct way of writing his method. +1 to your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `return dead.All(x => x);`

Comment: @KevinWells: I think we answered concurrently. So no problem. Furthermore I've made an error: the `Any` is defined without predicate while the `All` is not. So for some reason I was thinking the `All` didn't require an predicate as well.

Comment: @KevinWells If you take a look at comment time, you will see I posted the comment first, and if you take a look at that answer edit, you will see the first edit of answer was using dead.All(). SO I decided to post the answer :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei: did +1 btw, so no problem.

Comment: Fair enough, my mistake, I didn't see that when you first answered his answer was wrong. I just generally comment on the later answer when I see two of the same answer. I should have looked into the edit history first

Comment: @KevinWells no problem :) Hope you find both answers useful :)

Comment: @KevinWells: well there is no "*mistake*". I suggest we remove the comments, and continue with our lives ;).